# java - web search api for pmi

Tags: java, web-services, search, web, search-engine

I wish to search the web to get **number of hits for a query**, which will allow me to find [pmi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information)

Are there good java api implementations available which allow me to search web for free? I want to use search operators like "AND", "NOT", "OR","NEAR".
Some search engines[not java apis], with some query limits, I found were : [EntireWeb](http://www.entireweb.com/search_api/) , [Faroo](http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html), [Blekko](http://help.blekko.com/)

What about [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/index.html) : Can it be used for this purpose? As far as I understood, it is a crawler that creates an indexed set of pages, which can be queried efficiently.

If you have any ideas on the same, please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Try the tutorials from the [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)